# Visual Studio Wizard - Won't add project items to the correct folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to create a custom Visual Studio wizard to create generated code.

Everything works well but the only problem is that the project file won't be saved in right folder. I'm right clicking on a project folder and selecting 'New Item...' but the wizard saves the file in project root.

The code:

```
public class ProcedureClass : IDTWizard
{
    public void Execute(object Application, int hwndOwner, ref object[] ContextParams, ref object[] CustomParams, ref EnvDTE.wizardResult retval)
    {
        // Showing wizard dialog and generating code here...

        var projectItems = ContextParams[2] as ProjectItems;
        var project = projectItems.ContainingProject;
        retval = wizardResult.wizardResultSuccess;

        project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(tempFile, ContextParams[4]);
    }
}
```

Here is an image showing where I clicked and where the file has been created:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected given that your code uses projectItems.ContainingProject, which always returns the root project.
See my article

HOWTO: Navigate the files of a solution from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006004.aspx

The correct code would be:

- Get projectItems.Parent, which is an object, which in turn can be an EnvDTE.Project or an EnvDTE.ProjectItem.
- If it is an EnvDTE.Project, use Project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(..)
- If it is an EnvDTE.ProjectItem, use ProjectItem.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(...)

Comment: ProjectItems.Parent gave me exactly what I need.